# Upgrate Ubuntu Core 16 -> Ubuntu Core 20

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-core

I have a Rapberry Pi 2, with Ubuntu Core 16 running. Is there a way to upgrade to Ubuntu Core 20 without reinstalling the whole OS?

Thank you.